# Picking the set of coset representatives of a stabilizer under a group action

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-actions

My question is as follows:

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group that acts on finite set $A$.

Let $a \in A$.

Let $U$ be a set of left coset representatives of $Stab_{a}$.

Can $U$ be chosen such that for all $b$ in the orbit of $a$, $\exists \alpha\in U$ such that $\alpha b=a$?

It is easy to see that this is always possible if $Stab_{a}$ is normal since we can get the quotient group but the general result is less clear whether or not it is true.

edit: left coset rep

Comment: Yes, not only can this be done, it is unavoidable. Two elements of $G$ map $b$ to $a$ if and only if they are in the same right coset of $Stab_a$. This is a one line exercise.

Comment: @verret sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both map $b$ to $a$, then where does $\alpha\beta^{-1}$ map $a$? What can you conclude from that, with respect to cosets of $Stab_a$?

Comment: @verret yes, I agree they are in the same right coset of $Stab_{a}$. However, I don't see how the conclusion follows from here. I was talking about left coset representatives (sorry if that was not clear)

Comment: That makes a big difference! It is still true, but it is a bit harder now. In light of the previous discussion, you're asking if there exists a set of left cosets representative, that is also a set of right cosets representative. That is well-known to be the case, and follows for example from Hall's Marriage Theorem. See https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2020/03/27/halls-marriage-theorem/ for a discussion of this.

Comment: @verret I will read about it. thanks for your help